# How to determine whether a record with specific IMAGE data type already exists in the table?

Tags: database, t-sql, sql-server-2008

What is the most effective way to do that? I'm looking for a stored procedure, with returns me a new ID or an ID of the record with that image. Image could be up to 15-20MB, but mostly it will be 0,5-2MB.

Thanks for help,

Comment: There is a link here that explains it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751054/compare-images-in-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> most effective way

The most effective way I can think of is to use a persisted [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) for a hash value of the image column. Use [hashbytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) to calculate the hash and add a [unique constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166.aspx) on the computed column.

Table definition:

```
create table Images
(
  ID int identity primary key, 
  Img varbinary(max),
  ImgHash as convert(varbinary(16), hashbytes('MD5', Img)) persisted unique
)
```

Sample code against Images table:

```
insert into Images values 
(convert(varbinary(max), 'Image1')),
(convert(varbinary(max), 'Image2'))

declare @NewImage varbinary(max) = convert(varbinary(max), 'Image2')

select count(*)
from Images
where ImgHash = hashbytes('MD5', @NewImage)
```

The unique constraint creates an index that will be used in the query.

[image]

Your SP to add an image could look like this using [merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) and [output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) with a trick from this answer [UPDATE-no-op in SQL MERGE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316669/update-no-op-in-sql-merge-statement/5884720#5884720) provided by [Andriy M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297408/andriy-m).

```
create procedure Images_Add
  @NewImage varbinary(max)
as  

declare @dummy int

merge Images as T
using (select @NewImage, hashbytes('MD5', @NewImage)) as S(Img, ImgHash)
on T.ImgHash = S.ImgHash
when not matched then
  insert(Img) values(S.Img)
when matched then
  update set @dummy = 0  
output inserted.ID;
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that in a moment