# Use master.sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring in computed column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, calculated-columns

In my sql server table, I want to add a computed column that is a hash of other columns in the same table. Below is my table structure.

**Address:**
AddressID(int , PK)
AddressLine1 (nvarchar)
AddressLine2 (nvarchar)
City (nvarchar)
State (nvarchar)
AddressHash(computed column)

Below is what I want to get in my computed column:

```
MASTER.SYS.FN_VARBINTOHEXSUBSTRING(0, HASHBYTES('SHA1',COALESCE(AddressLine1, N'') + COALESCE(AddressLine2, N'') + COALESCE(City, N'') + COALESCE(State, N'')), 1, 0)
```

If I right-click the table and go to design and enter the above for "Formula" under "Computed Column Specification", I get the following error:

***- Unable to modify table.

A user-defined function name cannot be prefixed with a database name in this context.***

So I thought I would use a *user defined function* to calculate the hash and map that udf to formula.

Below is the code that I am using to create UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION udfHashAddress
(   
    @pAddressLine1 nvarchar(50), @pAddressLine2 nvarchar(50), @pCity nvarchar(50), @pState nvarchar(50))
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max) -- not sure what the correct size would be
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN   
    DECLARE @result nvarchar(max)   
    SELECT @result = MASTER.SYS.FN_VARBINTOHEXSUBSTRING(0, HASHBYTES('SHA1',COALESCE(@pAddressLine1, N'') + COALESCE(@pAddressLine2, N'') + COALESCE(@pCity, N'') + COALESCE(@pState, N'')), 1, 0)  
    RETURN @result
END
GO
```

But I get the following error with the above code:

***Cannot schema bind function 'udfHashAddress' because name 'MASTER.SYS.FN_VARBINTOHEXSUBSTRING' is invalid for schema binding. Names must be in two-part format and an object cannot reference itself.***

When I removed the "MASTER" db prefix I got this error:

***Cannot schema bind function 'udfHashAddress' because it references system object 'SYS.FN_VARBINTOHEXSUBSTRING'.***

Am I missing something here? Would appreciate any assistance/pointers.

Comment: Do you need it to be a string? Could you not use varbinary(20) instead? Have a look at this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807438/how-to-determine-whether-a-record-with-specific-image-data-type-already-exists-in/6809525#6809525 It uses md5 and varbinary(16).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using SQL Server 2008, have you tried simply:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), HASHBYTES('SHA1','string'), 2);
```

This will return upper case instead of lower case letters, but you can fix that with LOWER() if it's important.

Here is an example with your actual schema (created in tempdb on purpose):

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.[Address]
(
    AddressID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    AddressLine1 NVARCHAR(64),
    AddressLine2 NVARCHAR(64),
    City NVARCHAR(64),
    [State] NVARCHAR(64),
    AddressHash AS LOWER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(4000), HASHBYTES('SHA1', 
        COALESCE(AddressLine1, N'') + COALESCE(AddressLine2, N'') 
        + COALESCE(City, N'') + COALESCE([State], N'')), 2))
        --PERSISTED -- you could also persist it if desired
);

INSERT dbo.[Address]
    VALUES(1, 'foo', 'bar', 'blat', 'splunge'),
          (2, 'bar', 'foo', 'blag', 'splmger');

SELECT *, master.dbo.fn_varbintohexsubstring
    (0,
        HASHBYTES
        (
            'SHA1', 
            COALESCE(AddressLine1, N'') + COALESCE(AddressLine2, N'') 
            + COALESCE(City, N'') + COALESCE([State], N'')
        ), 1, 0)
        FROM dbo.[Address];
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.[Address];
```

Comment: PS you can put this in the computed column definition without referencing a UDF... however do whatever you can to avoid modifying a table using right-click, design. Use ALTER TABLE ... it's far less buggy and unintuitive.